# Content Encoding Error

Tags: php, encoding, content-type

I am having problem with website.
When I visited the website from **firefox** it show me

> "Content Encoding Error"

and from **Chrome** it shows me

> "ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED"

this is for 1and1 server.

but when I upload the same local website to another server **"ovh"** everything work perfectly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your server configuration etc.?

Comment: We need more than this to help you. Can you copy part of the code for a page, in particular the `<head>` since this can hold the Content-Type header to set encoding? It's also possibly a problem with how the server is configured. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think this is related to PHP, but with firewall settings, which might be filtering or restricting the data retrieved from one server which also explains why when you change to ovh, the page works fine.

Comment: Since you tagged this question with "PHP": You could try enabling `zlib.output_compression`in your php.ini: http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php

Comment: Thanks to you all, the problem was in the file application/settings/cache.php

Answer (score 0):

It might be a mismatch of the HTTP request headers and what you are actually delivering. Try turning off gzip encoding in HTTPD.